# autenticação site site VBA

Tags: vba

Estou realizando a raspagem de um site e estou colocando a autenticação do cookie,depois que logo no site vou no código fonte e copio a  autenticação, porque eu consigo fazer o login mas não consigo unir isso ao meu código principal, eu não quero fazer pelo Internet Explorer, tem que ser pelo Mozilla.

Estou usando provisoriamente a autenticação do Cookie

`.setRequestHeader "Cookie", "JSESSIONID=...`

---

Criei esta sub que autentica, mas como unir ao meu código principal que está raspando.

```
Public Sub Login()

    Dim xmlhttp As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim myurl As String

    myurl = "URL"

    xmlhttp.Open "POST", myurl, False

    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Connection", "keep-alive"

    xmlhttp.send "login=LOGIN&senha=SENHA"



    MsgBox (xmlhttp.responseText)

    End Sub
```

---

Essa Rotina loga no site, porém tenho outro código que faz a raspagem precisa unir a autenticação, antes de raspar 
`.setRequestHeader "Connection", "keep-alive"` 'NÃO RESOLVEU

`.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "LOGIN" & "SENHA"`  'NÃO RESOLVEU

`xmlhttp.send "login=LOGIN&senha=SENHA"`   'NÃO RESOLVEU

Estou usando duas URLs uma para logar e a outra para raspar mas não acontece nada como se não tivesse logado, as duas sub separadamente funcionam.

Comment: Você já acompanhou pelo navegador, para ver qual a requisição que o navegador faz, e quais cabeçalhos ele manda?